# Show notification on shiny app startup

Tags: r, shiny

In order to add a disclaimer to my app, I want to display a message at the launch of the app with `showNotification()`.

The user should **not** have to press a button (as per below) for the message to appear.

```
shinyApp(
ui = fluidPage(actionButton("show", "Show")),   
server = function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$show, {
      showNotification("This is a notification.")
    })   
})
```

Comment: see the first example [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-events.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change to `observe`

```
   observe({
      showNotification("This is a notification.")
    })
```